# Exception in Application start method related error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I was trying to run the sample JavaFX project from IntelliJ Idea 20.1. The program is a sample program. The structure is

[image: project structure]

and the code is the same, I changed nothing

[image: Main.java code]

[image: fxml code simple hello world]

I am using jdk 11, openjfx 17, and I am getting this error, I do not understand the cause I tried many possible solutions nothing seems to work.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x4800c48b) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x4800c48b
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2135)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:290)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Comment: I don’t know what the sample JavaFX project is, nor the cause of your error, but the easiest way to get JavaFX working in Idea is to use the [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) IMO.  I’d also advise jdk 17 rather than 11.

Comment: Please don’t screenshot code (and fxml), paste it as text formatted as code (just indent 4 spaces).

Comment: Likely, you've set `--add-modules` somewhere but you forgot to include `javafx.fxml`.

Comment: Use the IDE New Project Wizard to create a proper javaFX project that would work correctly with JDK 9+ versions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The cause of my error was a simple module configuration, I finally added the JavaFX library on the project module and removed the VM option arguments and it worked.

Thank you, everyone, for your comments!